# Read the column of a selected excel file using python, Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want read the **selected** Excel file`s sheet data eg.(Cell: A1)

importPage.html

```
<form  enctype='multipart/form-data'  method="post" action="/import/"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
    <div class="card card-login mx-auto mt-5">
        <h2 class="card-header text-center">Import File</h2>
      <div class="card-body">
        <fieldset class="module aligned uploadFileForm">
            <div class="form-row">
              <label for="import_file">File to import:</label>
              <input type="file" name="import_file" required="" id="import_file">
            </div>

        </fieldset>
        <div class="">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-5 float-right" value="Submit">
            
        </div>
        {% if message %}
            <div class="alert alert-warning">
            {{message}}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    
    </div>
</form>
```

views.py

```
import os
import xlrd

class Import(View):
    template_name = 'importPage.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'login' not in request.session:
            return redirect('index')
        return render(request, self.template_name)
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        message = ''
        ExcelFile = request.FILES['import_file']   

        ExcelFileloc = ExcelFile.temp_name 
        
        #loc=(r"D:Master.xlsx") 
        loc=(ExcelFileloc)

        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
        sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
        A1= sheet.cell_value(0,0)                          
                    
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"message":A1})
```

I could read the cell data if the path is given directly

```
loc=(r"D:Master.xlsx")
```

But I want the selected file path automatically when the file is selected

```
ExcelFileloc = ExcelFile.temp_name 
loc=(ExcelFileloc)
```

It gives an error::. object has no attribute 'temp_name'

How to allocate the selected files location to loc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import xlrd
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage


class Import(View):
    template_name = 'importPage.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'login' not in request.session:
            return redirect('index')
        return render(request, self.template_name)
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        message = ''
        ExcelFile = request.FILES['import_file']   

        fs = FileSystemStorage()

        # Create a folder 'excelFile' to store the files
        filename = fs.save('excelFile/'+ExcelFile.name, ExcelFile)
        ExcelFileloc = fs.url(filename)
                
        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(ExcelFileloc)
        
        sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
        A1= sheet.cell_value(0,0)                          
                    
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"message":A1})
```